# How to recombine seasonally decomposed stl components in R

Tags: r, time-series

I want to recombine the seasonal components to the seasonally adjusted components for a time series that is decomposed by stl. For example:

```
    library(fpp)
    fit <- stl(elecequip, s.window=7)
    plot(fit)

    sa_fit <- seasadj(fit)
```

How do I combine the seasonal component to sa_fit so that I get back the original seasonal data ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for code?

Comment: @gung it seems that you weren't always so strict about coding question [in the past](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r) (or CV users/mods in general), weren't you?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, you're right: the protocol for coding questions has evolved & become clearer over time. That question is very old. We now send questions that only need coding help to SO & deal w/ questions that need stats help here.

Answer (score 5):

In order to get the attributes of an unfamiliar (to you) class in R use `attributes`.

A quick look will show you that you need the `time.series` attribute, as in

```
unadjusted <- fit$time.series[, 1] + sa_fit
```

You can then check that the `unadjusted` equals to the original data by using `all.equal`

```
all.equal(unadjusted, elecequip)
## [1] TRUE
```